# Magento Payment transaction failed Email Recipient

Tags: email, transactions, magento

In Magento a "Payment transaction failed" email is sent out if there is a problem with payment.

Is there any way to add more recipients to that email? I can't see any way how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: How to set payment failed mail to a customer? @sulman

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I found it:

System->Configuration->Checkout->Payment Failed Emails->Send Payment Failed Email Copy To

Comment: In the future, this extension can help you quickly search the system config section. http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/alanstorm/extension/3824/system_configuration_search

Comment: Thanks Alan. Very handy extension.